# Property of non-empty sets on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Let A,B,C non-empty sets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A \cap C = B \cap C$ and $A \cup C = B \cup C.$ Show that $A = B$.

Since $A \cap B = B \cap C$ we know that both sets A and B share the same elements as C. Also since $A \cup C = B \cup C$, we know that at the set of elements in at least one of set A and C is the same as the set of elements in at least one of sets B and C.

Therefore we can say $((A \cup B) - C) + A \cap B = ((B \cup C) - C) \Rightarrow A = B.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formal proof can be given as follows:

Let $x \in A$. Then, $x \in A \cup C = B \cup C$. Hence $x \in B$ or $x \in C$. If $x \in B$, we are done. Otherwise, $x \in C$, so $x \in A \cap C = B \cap C$ and so $x \in B$. So $A \subset B$.

Let $x \in B$. Then, $x \in B \cup C = A \cup C$. Hence $x \in A$ or $x \in C$. If $x \in A$, we are done. Otherwise, $x \in C$, so $x \in B \cap C = A \cap C$ and so $x \in A$. So $B \subset A$.

Hence $A = B$. There was nothing about real numbers used here so it would apply for any sets $A,B,C$.